Mysql has gone away or Connection refused suddenly on running tests
from time to time, when running integration tests in gitlab CI, I am reaching the errors  like "Connection refused" OR "Mysql server has gone away".
This is my gitlab-ci mysql configuration
    - name: ${DOCKER_HUB_PROXY}/mysql:8.0.32
      alias: mysql
      command: [ "--max-allowed-packet=500M", "--log-error-verbosity=3", "--connect-timeout=100", "--thread-cache-size=100", "--innodb-io-capacity=500", "--wait-timeout=600" ]
      variables:
          KUBERNETES_SERVICE_CPU_LIMIT: "1"
          KUBERNETES_SERVICE_CPU_REQUEST: "1"
          KUBERNETES_SERVICE_MEMORY_REQUEST: "1Gi"
          KUBERNETES_SERVICE_MEMORY_LIMIT: "2Gi"

